# How do I proceed beyond restarting my pc after Ubuntu 14.04 install?

Tags: live-usb

I have to keep the bootable usb inserted in order to load Ubuntu even after installation in the hard drive, and when it opens up it is the initial try or install menu which existed before installation. While working with partitions, I formatted the windows seven loader partition accidently. Once, after restart, the screen showed 'Missing Operating system' message, though that isn't the case now.

Comment: I didn't get it: does Ubuntu get loaded now without the bootable USB inserted, or not? Side note: 14.04 is ancient, consider using 18.04.

Comment: No, it isn't loading without the bootable usb.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me once. Probably the GRUB is broken.

Try this:

1. Plug your bootable USB stick and boot from it
2. Install and run `boot repair`:

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair`

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair`

3. Use the option `recommended repair`
4. Unplug the bootable USB and try to boot from the hard drive (maybe you will have to change the boot order in the BIOS)

---

PS: 14.04 is a little bit old, I would recommend you to install Ubuntu 16.04